# ORDER BY is taking too much time when executed for VIEW

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, sql-view

I have a relatively complicated set up. I'm using SQL Server 2012 with 3 linked servers which are IBM DB2 servers. I have several queries which join tables from all three linked servers to fetch data. Due to some specifics of the version that I'm using I can't use some OLAP functions directly so since an upgrade is not an option the workaround was to create views and execute those functions on the views. One problem that I'm facing right now is that using `ORDER BY` from the view almost triples up the time needed for the view to be executed.

When I execute the only with `SELECT` it takes 24 seconds (Yeah, I know we talk about ridiculous times here, but still, I want to fix the problem with the order by since I'm not allowed to change the queries to the DB2 servers but the `order by` is on my side), when I use `ORDER BY` it goes from 68 to 80 seconds depending on which column I'm ordering on. I can't create a schemabound view because it's now allowed with `OpenQuery`, I've read the anyways it's not allowed to use `ORDER BY` when creating a view, I haven't tried that but since I need the order by to be available on multiple columns it's not a n option unless I create as much views as columns I have which sounds kinda ridiculous but... dunno.

Since I have trivial knowledge about `SQL` at general I'm not sure what is the best choice here. Even if the execution times are fixed I don't want my `Order by` clause to be so much time consuming compared to the time needed for the whole query. If I can make it as fast as it is when I execute it directly in the query - when I don't use view and I add the `ORDER BY` to the initial `query` the original time is 24 seconds and then it goes up to 36 which in percents is still much better than the performance when the same `ORDER BY` function is executed from the view.

So my questions are - what causes the `ORDER BY` to be executed so slow from the view and how can I make it as fast as if it was part from the original query, also, if this is just not possible, how can I reduce the huge time it takes?

Comment: From what I understand, you shouldn't define a view with an order by because when you actually call the view it won't (necessarily) be ordered. If you need it in order explicitly order by when you call it. If it is slow when explicitly ordering it make sure there are indexes on the source columns that you are using in the order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views use different execution plans than the queries that make them.  This is, in my opinion, a bit of a shortcoming of views.  `ORDER BY` is a particularly expensive command, so it makes the difference in execution plans very noticeable.

The alternative to this issue I've found was going the Table Valued Function route as it does appear to use the same execution plan as just running the query.

Here's a decent write-up of Table Valued Functions:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx